# Check the amount of objects inside an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view, how can I check how many objects there are inside an instance variable?

I want to know how many "animals" I got inside the `@animals` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout:

`@animals.count`  `@animals.size` `@animals.length`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works if you have two or more object in the variable. But when there is only one object inside the variable and I run one of the methods I get an error. Do you know how I can check if there is only one object inside?

Comment: More pertinent would be checking why your variable can be of two types. I'd suggest you change your code to be sure it is always an array, even if only holding one object. If you need help doing so, post the code.

Comment: Or you could do it like this: `Array(@animals).count`, which will force the object into an array if it isn't an array already.

Comment: @Matt: could you please check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044895/rails-check-if-an-instance-variable-has-one-or-more-objects

Comment: @allegutta, I believe so. It's a common Ruby idiom.